# PHP SQL: Selecting fields from three tables that are not interlinked

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently facing a problem where I am unable to link 3 separate SQL tables. Below are the relevant bits of the different tables.

```
Comments
commentID userID staffID comment   comment_date
       52   1037       0 sadsadsa   2016-01-12
       54      0    1050 asda       2016-01-12

Users
userID first_name last_name 
  1036 Janet      Ang       
  1037 glenn      tan       

Staffs
staffID staffName 
   1001 Ling Ling 
   1011 Lee Ming  
   1003 Joyce     
   1010 Titus     
   1008 Vivian    
   1005 Vincent   
   1006 Alex      
   1046 Glenn     
   1047 Glenn2    
   1048 glennjr2  
   1049 glenn3    
   1050 glenn4
```

I am currently trying to retreive comments made by both users and staffs, and the three tables are not interlinked. The "comments" table are linked to both "users" and "staffs" table, but the "users" and "staffs" table are not linked together. I am using this query

```
SELECT comments.comment, users.first_name, users.last_name, staffs.staffName, comments.comment_date 
                        FROM comments  
                        INNER JOIN users  
                        on comments.userID = users.userID 
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN staffs 
                        on comments.staffID = staffs.staffID 
                        WHERE comments.videoID = $vid_id
```

Can anyone help to see how can I change my query to solve my problem? Thankful for any help given.

Comment: use left join in both, if value is not exists in other table like user and staff then it will return null in relative field

Comment: As far as I can see, using INNER JOIN in both should work.

Comment: @Baruchel, tried to execute the query, no results showed up.

Answer (score 1):

You can use INNER JOIN for both tables `(users,staffs)` with `comments` table:

**Example:**

```
SELECT comments.comment, users.first_name, users.last_name, staffs.staffName, comments.comment_date
FROM comments
INNER JOIN users ON comments.userID = users.userID
INNER JOIN staffs ON comments.staffID = staffs.staffID
WHERE comments.videoID = $vid_id
```

After this, you will get the two results, one for `users` and one for `staffs`.

If you need all users and staffs either `comments` available or not than you can use `LEFT JOIN` with same query.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but for inner join to work correctly, all three tables must have a field in common, right? Currently, the staffs table is linked to comments table via staffID, while users table is linked to comments table via usersID, but I have no field in common between staffs, users, and comments.

Comment: @JunJie: comments table is your bridge table, than no need to add relation, u can already get the relation from comments table..

Comment: @JunJie: it just a suggestion, create a single table for staff and users, and categories with user_type (user =1, staff=2)... just suggestion not related to your question.

Comment: I fully agree with your suggestion. However, this is for a school group project with the deadline nearing, and creating another table will affect my group mates' scope.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the UNION operation:

Example:

```html
( SELECT comments.comment, CONCAT(users.first_name, " ", users.last_name) as name, comments.comment_date, "User" as type
FROM comments, users 
WHERE comments.userID = users.userID
  AND comments.videoID = $vid_id )

UNION

( SELECT comments.comment, CONCAT(staffs.staffName) as name, comments.comment_date, "Staff" as type
FROM comments, staffs 
WHERE comments.staffID = staffs.staffID
  AND comments.videoID = $vid_id )
```